# Using a timer / scheduler with calendar

Tags: java, timer, calendar

**[In Java]** Hey, I searched a lot on the web and the only thing I found doesn't work for me. What I need is to execute a specific task every week from the user's calendar. I want it to count time even if the user didn't open the application. What I found on internet would reset the calendar everytime the user would launch the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this question is too broad for the Stack Overflow format, where questions need to be answerable (if this is a word) in a few paragraphs. Maybe if you share you ideas you have, someone may comment on whether they will work or possible improvements.

Comment: I’m thinking: persist the last time the task was performed. On app launch, check if more than a week ago. If it is, execute immediately. If not, start a timer to execute a week after last time.

Comment: That looks like a good idea... I'll give it a try...

Comment: @OleV.V. Seems like it will work. I'm currently storing the date and time everytime I run the reset. But how can I check if the date is one week late ? I only know isEqual() isAfter() and isBefore()

Comment: `plus(1, ChronoUnit.WEEKS)`? Depends on the type you use for your last execution time.

Comment: That's what I did and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m thinking: persist the last time the task was performed. On app launch, check if more than a week ago. If it is, execute immediately. If not, start a timer to execute a week after last time.

How to find the next execution time one week after the previous execution time? It depends on the type you use for your last execution time, but many `java.time` types will accept `plus(1, ChronoUnit.WEEKS)`. Some also have a `plusWeeks` method for even greater convenience.

Comment: I was using localdate, which worked fine with.

Answer (score 0):

Create "smart" calendar with method `long nextExecutionTime(long currentTime)` that accept current time and return time of next execution time, make it persistence with help of db. In time of your app start fetch this calendar from db and get next execution time, count to this time if you counted to this time execute task and get next execution time with help of this method.